# Manipulate several files in PHP

Tags: php, file, input

I'm trying to import data from multiple .csv in a web app thanks to a single input, but I'm struggling manipulating $_FILES.

All I want to do is separating files into two arrays according to their names. I'm not able to upload these files on the server.

This is the input in the form page used to upload files :

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="inputrapports" accept=".csv" multiple="true"/>
```

In my action page, i'm doing this :

```
$files=$_FILES['file'];
$q=array();
$c=array();
foreach($files as $file){
    if(strtoupper(substr(str_replace(' ','',$file['name']),7,1))=="Q"){
        $q[]=$file;
    }else{
        $c[]=$file;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. So I tried this :

```
foreach($files['name'] as $f){
    echo $f; //I'm getting the name
}
foreach($files as $f){
    echo $f['name']; //I'm not
}
```

I could use the first attempt shown above, but in this case I won't be able to put the entire array of the file in the appropriate array.

Can you explain me why this two attempts give different answers ?

Could you help me find a solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the var_dump of the $_FILES?

Comment: I'm using this to avoid writing $_FILES['file'] every time

Comment: yeah I think so, but the output of var_dump($_FILES) would be helpful.

Comment: Here it is : array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(43) "Rapport Quotidien activitÃ© 09-07-2014.csv" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "text/csv" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(23) "/srv/data/tmp/phphwWN6K" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(291) } }

Comment: Ok, I see the problem... Instead of the expected `$_FILES['file'][0]['name']` php builds `$_FILES['file']['name'][0]`.

Comment: `foreach($files as $f){echo $f['name'][0];}` isn't working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dirty way to solve this is:

```
$files = $_FILES['file'];
for($i=0;$i<count($files['tmp_name']); $i++)
{
    echo $files['name'][$i];
}
```

Another approach is from the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.files.php#109958):

```
function diverse_array($vector) { 
    $result = array(); 
    foreach($vector as $key1 => $value1) 
        foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2) 
            $result[$key2][$key1] = $value2; 
    return $result; 
}

$files = diverse_array($_FILES["file"]);
```

And then proceed with your first foreach.

```
$q=array();
$c=array();
foreach($files as $file){
    if(strtoupper(substr(str_replace(' ','',$file['name']),7,1))=="Q"){
        $q[]=$file;
    }else{
        $c[]=$file;
    }
}
```

Comment: About your dirty way, i think you would have written echo `$files['tmp_name'][$i];`. But in this case, i'm not able to match the 7th char of the string.

Comment: Maybe because the Q is the 9th char?

Comment: Not with `str_replace(' ','',$file['name']),7,1`.

Comment: Anyway, it works now thanks to the `diverse_array` function. Thank you!